# Can you prompt a download based on form submitted data within an ajax response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I use AJAX POST to send form data to an external script and attempting to hide the form on submit and prompt the user to download the script.

The script itself works well (uses fpdf to output pdf file for download). For some reason, prompting the user to download though never comes through.

My Ajax request is currently:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "file.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                //hide the form
                $('#form').fadeOut('slow');

                //display results
                $('#form_results').fadeIn('slow');
                $("#form_results").html(html);
            }       
        });
```

file.php (on it own) will generate and display a PDF using FPDF. By setting the Output to I, the document is output to a browser, setting to 'D', it would normally force a download if I were simply accessing file.php directly.

any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean, "prompting the user to download"?  None of the code you posted has any apparent relationship to prompting.

Comment: I'm guessing the response from `file.php` you expect to be a PDF file.

Comment: @Pointy The op is trying to make the result of an AJAX call be a forced download, sort of when you link someone to an mp3 file and it sends headers to prevent movie players from playing it automatically and instead force a download

Comment: @marcel and @onteria - you are both correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't force a download directly from an ajax call. Your best bet is to submit the form through ajax and have ajax respond with a url that you can redirect the user to that starts the download. However, just an FYI, using location.href to a page that sends a header to force download in IE will cause the yellow security bar to appear on the top of the page. This happens in IE8, not sure about other versions. FF and Chrome don't have a problem with it.

Edit:

Just wanted to add, when you do redirect someone to a page that forces download, they don't actually leave the page they currently are on. So they won't have to reload an ajax page or anything. The download dialog will just show up. So if you are on index.php and you say location.href='download.php' and download.php forces a download. You just get the download dialog and don't leave index.php.

Edit2:

there are actually quite a few questions about this already.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+download+over+ajax

Comment: thanks for your responses. I did a fairly thorough search before on the topic and found nothing like the issue I was facing ultimately. While some are looking to force a download of an image or document from file (yes I suppose similar), my document is actually built on a second page and can then be output to the user. I'll continue to investigate and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @JM4 whether the document is built in php or read from disk really won't make much of a difference when it comes to forcing a download. whether you build the file in php and echo out the results or you read a file in and echo out what was read, it will have the same download result. If you wanted it to be as seamless as possible in this case, instead of using ajax to do the post, make a form with hidden elements and use javascript to submit it. Your page will gets its post values and the script doesn't need to save to disk and then redirect to a download page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you try to show results but it is in form, which is hidden. Try something like :

```
            //hide the form
            $('#form').children().fadeOut('slow');

            //display results
            $('#form results').fadeIn('slow');
            $("#form results").html(html);
```

This way, every children will be hidden but the parent itself won't.

Comment: thanks but this is incorrect. My fault for not explaining but the DIV ID for form_results is outside of the form itself. If i change the text of file.php to simply echo a statement and exit it displays proper